# Interactive Reports: Customized column Heading in UI using page items

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have created Interactive Report based on a table. I want to generate customized column heading using page items to be displayed in UI.

I have Page item `P1_ITEM1` (source: *"SQL Query returning single row"*).

I have used above mentioned item in Heading Space in Report Attribute of IR as `&P1_ITEM1.` for a column.

But when I am running the report, I am getting blank/null headings, no name.

Please help me on this issue.

*Oracle DB: 11.2g; 
APEX Version: 4.2*

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because SQL query for `P1_ITEM1` runs after heading of Interactive Report rendering.

Try to move your item before IR region or create PL/SQL process (point - Before Region)

```
SELECT ...
  INTO :P1_ITEM1 
  FROM ...
 WHERE ...;
```

and reset Source Type for `P1_ITEM1` to Static Assignement. I tried both methods, it's working.

APEX 5 example link https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54028:3:10869386854547::YES but also working on APEX 4.